# Run process in SQL Server CLR stored procedure but Process.OutputDataReceived not firing

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlclr

I want to run process in SQL Server CLR this my code:

```
[SqlProcedure]
private static int RunExecutable()
{
     SqlDataRecord sqlDataRecord = new SqlDataRecord(new SqlMetaData("message", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 1L));
     SqlContext.Pipe.SendResultsStart(sqlDataRecord);
     int lineCount = 0;

     Process process = new Process();
     process.StartInfo.FileName = "ipconfig.exe";
     process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
     process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
     process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
     process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
     process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
     process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler((sender, e) =>
            {
                    sqlDataRecord.SetString(0, "OnDataReceived");
                    SqlContext.Pipe.SendResultsRow(sqlDataRecord);

                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
                    {
                        lineCount++;
                        sqlDataRecord.SetString(0, "[" + lineCount + "]: " + e.Data);
                        SqlContext.Pipe.SendResultsRow(sqlDataRecord);
                    }
            });

     process.Start();
     process.BeginOutputReadLine();

     while (!process.HasExited)
     {
         sqlDataRecord.SetString(0, "process WaitForExit ");
         SqlContext.Pipe.SendResultsRow(sqlDataRecord);
         process.WaitForExit(300);
     }
}
```

and `ipconfig.exe` runs (I see in results "process WaitForExit"), but the `OutputDataReceived` event is not triggered.

The assembly was created in SQL Server 2019 Enterprise with `PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE;`. If I run the same code as the standard console application everything works fine

Comment: Have you considered using [`Ping.Send`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ping?view=net-5.0)? By the way you should dispose `process` with a `using` block

Answer (score 3):

That's going to require a background thread to run the event while you block the session's thread on `WaitForExit`.  I'm not surprised it doesn't work in SQLCLR, which is a very different .NET Framework host than a console application.

And even if the event fires, you could not access `SqlContext.Pipe` from a thread other than the thread that called into the method.

Instead perform blocking reads of StandardOutput using the thread that called into your method, like this:

```
static IEnumerable<string> GetOutputLines(string exeName, string args = null)
{ 
    Process process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = exeName;
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

    process.Start();
    
    while ( true )
    {
        var line = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
        if (line == null)
            break;
        yield return line;
    }

    process.WaitForExit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks,  I figured out that the problem was sending the result to the DataReceivedEventHandler. Possibly because the DataReceivedEventHandler is being called on a different thread.

Answer (score 0):

+1 to David for answering the general question of how to best capture and return command-line output.

However, for your specific scenario of running **ipconfig.exe** and returning all of the output, I think you would be *far* better served by simply using:

[NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getallnetworkinterfaces)

I would try that first. This might require you to load the **System.Net.NetworkInformation.dll** Framework library as `UNSAFE` in the same database, but you are already doing "unsafe" operations by shelling out to the OS, so at least this is handled in managed code.

Comment: ipconfig.exe is just test app, in my case i run an other application.